# SaveAs Error In VB Script To Make PDF From Docx

Tags: pdf, vbscript, docx

I run the code below in CMD window to convert a ~200 page .Docx file to a PDF:

```
  Set App       = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
  Set AVDoc     = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
  Set PDDoc     = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
  AVDoc.Open    "C:\Users\rodger.beard\Desktop\DTS User Guide.docx", ""
  SET PDDoc     = AVDoc.GetPDDoc
  PDDoc.SaveAS  1, "C:\Users\rodger.beard\Desktop\DTS User Guide.pdf"
  AVDoc.Close   False
  PDDoc.Close
  App.Exit
  Set AcroApp   = Nothing
  Set AVDoc     = Nothing
  Set PDDoc     = Nothing
```

I get error 800A01B on line 6, PDDoc.SaveAs - "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I erred when pasting in line 4 of the code.  There should be 2 double quotes at the end of the line.

Comment: Maybe try `PDDoc.Save`?

Comment: You know you can edit your question to fix issues like that?

Answer (score 0):

If the object does not support the method, then RTFM (Read the function manual).

You can use Adobe Acrobat to read all its PDF manuals especially in this case, that part may be working?

However Adobe no longer make their docs easy i.e they are NOT accessible just like their content? They are replaced by HTML !

So to find the best copy of acrobatsdk_iacguide.pdf (The one that you read before coding) may be here. https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/index.html

So the stated object is valid `PDDoc` but they fail to show what are the valid methods and I have to say the historic one was [`.Save`](https://github.com/VincentGabrielVallee/VincentGabrielVallee/blob/main/acrobatsdk_iacguide.pdf) now listed as https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.html#acroexch-pddoc
So I suggest use or try without brackets

```
PDDoc.Save  (1, "C:\Users\rodger.beard\Desktop\DTS User Guide.pdf")
```

more details at https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.html#save

Comment: Agreed, the docs are not helpful.  I especially laughed at the reference to 50 methods,, that then are not documented.  And nothing on their properties either of course.

I tried replacing Save as a replacement for SaveAs.  Also tried changing 1 to "1". 

The process runs 3 minutes before displaying fatal error..  A Docx. temp file is created so I l know the Word doc has been processed.  The PDF is apparently created successfully too but I wonder if this might be the sort of the issue.

Does .GetPDDoc need a properity to specify input is Word not PFD?

Comment: K J., you are correct that DC Reader won't work.  I'm using Acrobat Pro DC which does support AccroExch.App functionality.

Comment: I tried calling out just the path rather than path & file name.  Same error.

Comment: Below is the code that runs within throwing an error.  However, it does not create the output PDF.  There is a diaglog box with progress bar titled Creating Adobe PDF that says "Please wait, reading Adobe PDF" which appears briefly.  It closes when only 5% full.

Comment: The code now runs without error.  However, there is no output PDF.  A progress bar in a dialog box "titled Creating Adobe PDF" says "Please wait, reading Adobe PDF" appears briefly.  It closes when the progress bar only 5% full.

The latest code replaces lines 5 and6 with:
Set AVDoc     = App.GetActiveDoc
Set PDDoc     = AVDoc.GetPDDoc
PDDoc.Save      PDSaveFull, "C:\Users\rodger.beard\Desktop\DTS User Guide.pdf"